# Dynamic sizing of the StackPanel

Tags: java, gwt

I am developing a Graphical User Interface based on GWT. I am not an expert in GUIs and GWT at all. In this way, what I am doing is creating a StackLayoutPanel inside a while loop as follows:

```
while(mainIterator.hasNext()){
    stackLayoutPanel.add(internalVerticalPanel, sZone, 30);
}
```

I omit the information of the internalVerticalPanel object, although basically are labels and HorizontalPanels.

However, this internalVerticalPanel does not always contains the same number of objects, therefore, the size is different on each iteration. Then, when showing the information, I have noticed that the total size of the StackPanel is divided by the number of headers or elements contained. What I would like to do is to establish the size for each header in order to adjust the size to the content of the VerticalPanel. I mean, instead of having elements with the same size, I would like to have each element with the size associated to the content. Is it possible? If so, how?

***Edit***: I have carried out the suggestion given in the response, but this is not the solution. As you can see in the attached image what is changed is the size of the header, but I want to keep the header and modify the size of the internal content. Now, the internalVerticalPanel is hidden behind the header.

[image]

In the following two pìctures you can see two examples, one with data to be shown and the Panel is well fixed, meanwhile in the second one there is no data and a big empty space. I want to resize these spaces in function of the available data to be drawn.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked this at runtime, but it seems to me that you could do

```
int myDesiredHeight = 0;    
while(mainIterator.hasNext()){
    stackLayoutPanel.add(internalVerticalPanel, sZone, 30);
    myDesiredHeight += 30;
}
stackLayoutPanel.setHeight(myDesiredHeight + "px");
```

This way you adjust the size of the stacklayoutpanel to accommodate the content.
About the different size for the headers, I think that this type of panel accepts custom headers or safe html, so you should be able to style your headers quite easily, e.g. using this method (StackLayoutPanel, line 168 in GWT 2.7) :

```
public void add(final Widget widget, SafeHtml header, double headerSize) {...}
```

Edit : you can try something along the lines of:

```
StackLayoutPanel stackLayoutPanel = new StackLayoutPanel(Style.Unit.PX);

VerticalPanel myWidget1 = new VerticalPanel();
SafeHtml myHeader1 = SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("My header 1 title");

VerticalPanel myWidget2 = new VerticalPanel();
SafeHtml myHeader2 = SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("My header 2 title");

stackLayoutPanel.add(myWidget1,myHeader1,100);
stackLayoutPanel.add(myWidget2,myHeader2,50);

// and so on
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response! If I understand your code, at the end, you set a overall size which is divided by the number of headers, right? However, what I am looking for is to avoid this split. I mean, a StackPanel of 1000px with 10 headers will draw 10 stack parts being each one of 100px. In contrast, I want to paint 10 stack parts containing verticalPanels of different sizes (1st 200px, 2nd 50px and so on). In my case the SafeHtml header is a simple String with the name.

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer to show an example of SafeHtml headers with different heights.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it along this week and I will let you know the result!! Thanks again!!